# I want to create the ball movement like the one in 'chilly snow' game. I want to curve the ball, but it revolves

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am new to unity and don't know a lot of stuff. I've been watching tutorials and I saw one in which the guy created a replica of famous 'Chilly Snow'. The game is complete but the movement of ball isn't like the one in chilly snow. The ball starts orbiting continuously when I press mouse button. I wanted to know how to create that kind of movement, so that the ball turns left and right in a curve but doesn't go in to an orbit. I googled a lot but wasn't able to find my required result. I would really appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction. Images are attached.[Chilly Snow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUoNF.jpg)   |   [Movement of my ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV00u.jpg)

```
public class movement : MonoBehaviour {

private float points;
public float playerSpeed;
private float rotationSpeed;
public Text score;
private bool isMovingLeft;
public GameObject player;
public bool isDead;




void Start () {

    Time.timeScale = 0;
    isDead = false;
    isMovingLeft = true;
    points = 0;



}


void Update () 
{
    if (isDead == false) 
    {
        points += Time.deltaTime;
    }

    transform.Translate (Vector3.down * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        isMovingLeft = !isMovingLeft;
        rotationSpeed += 0.5f * Time.deltaTime;

    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) 
    {
        rotationSpeed = 1f;
    }

    if (isMovingLeft) {
        rotationSpeed += 1.5f * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Rotate(0,0,rotationSpeed);

    } else
        transform.Rotate(0,0, - rotationSpeed);
}


void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Obstacle") {
        Die ();
    }
}

public void Die()
{


    playerSpeed = 0f;
    isDead = true;
    Invoke ("Restart", 2f);

}

void Restart(){

    SceneManager.LoadScene ("Ski_scene_1");

}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    score.GetComponent<Text>().text = points.ToString("0");
}
```

}

Comment: An idea of how you are currently doing it would help, show some code so we can see what you have tried.

Comment: @Eddge I've added the code, I would really appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: Do you need to rotate the object? or is that a matter of preference?  in the comments below you said you want the ball to turn left and right I am assuming you mean exactly how it does in that game?  with the curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would approach it without doing a rotation... using your code.

```
public class movement : MonoBehaviour {

private float points;
public Text score;
public GameObject player;
public bool isDead;

private float currentXSpeed;
private float targetSpeed;
public float maxXSpeed;
public float speedChange;

void Start () {
    Time.timeScale = 0;
    isDead = false;
    isMovingLeft = true;
    points = 0;
    targetSpeed = maxXSpeed;
}


void Update () 
{
    if (isDead == false) 
    {
        points += Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
         Time.timeScale = 1;
         targetSpeed = -targetSpeed;
    }

    currentSpeed = mathf.MoveTowards(currentSpeed, targetSpeed, speedChange * Time.deltaTime);
    Vector3 movementDirection = new Vector3(currentSpeed, Vector3.down.y * playerSpeed, 0.0f);
    transform.Translate (movementDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Obstacle") {
        Die ();
    }
}

public void Die()
{
    playerSpeed = 0f;
    isDead = true;
    Invoke ("Restart", 2f);
}

void Restart(){
    SceneManager.LoadScene ("Ski_scene_1");
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    score.GetComponent<Text>().text = points.ToString("0");
}

}
```

Comment: I was stuck at this for days, finally it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need something like sinusoidal movement or any other graph you fancy.

An example would be for this is like;

```
gameObject.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime*cubeSpeed);

gameObject.transform.position += transform.up * Mathf.Sin (Time.fixedTime * 3.0f  ) * 0.1f;
```

Above pseudo is for 2D graph simulation, can be adapted to your situation.

The object is always moving to right and going up and down while making a sinusoidal movement. Because the up and down speed is not fixed hence you get the *sinusoidal* or *like sinusoidal* movement.

In your case, while the object is always going down it will make the *sinusoidal* movement to left and right.

Your movement is based on the rotation so, if you give this *sinusoidal* speed as your rotation speed, you can achieve this.

---

Another aproach can be *lerp* or *slerp*

Lerp allows you to make kinda smooth transactions between 2 vectors.

Like moving from pointA to pointB in X seconds.

For rotation you will need `Quaternion.Lerp` There is a great answer on [Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/643141/how-can-i-lerp-an-objects-rotation.html) you can check that if you haven't before.

---

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tried both methods, but they didn't work. The ball has stopped going back up but still, the left and right transition is not smooth.
Sinusoidal function kind of did the job but the ball automatically goes left and right and I want the ball to move left and right on mouse click. 
The search continues...